# How do I duplicate a Telegram channel without a bot using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to create a copy from a certain channel in Telegram to the channel I created. I need him to just move all the messages and files there in order without credit. I use telethon and for now this is my level :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 19...

api_hash = '9c1aa....'

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)


client.send_message("someone", "hi (my level is amazing right ?)")



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

If someone can answer and maybe explain a little how to do it, I would be very happy.

thanks

Comment: You could try using the Telegram API to get a list of all the messages and files in the channel you want to copy, and then use the Telegram API to send those messages and files to your own channel,I don't have a coding example for you, but you can find the documentation for the Telegram API here: https://core.telegram.org/api.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`msgs = await client.get_messages(from_chat)` it returns a list of channel messages and
`for msg in msgs: await client.send_messages(to_chat, x)`
use this method and resend it to your desired channels
full code:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient


client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start()

async def sendMessages():
    msgs = await client.get_messages(from_chat)
    for msg in msgs:
        await client.send_message(to_chat, msg)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(sendMessages())
```

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. Try to answer by adapting code from the op and providing all required information within you answer.

Comment: it gives me an error :  msgs = await client.get_messages(from_chat)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 19...

api_hash = '9c1aa....'

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash).start()

async def sendMessage():
     msgs = await client.get_messages(from_chat)
     for x in msgs: 
         await client.send_messages(to_chat, x)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Comment: I really thank you and appreciate your help but can you please explain me why I am getting this error?                                                                           
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

Comment: I copied exactly the code you sent and just added the 'from_chat' and the 'to_chat'  into sendNessage()

Comment: It's not an error it's an warning tht the method is deprecated in new python versions